# Image Storage & linking Solution Needed

Tags: image, hyperlink, storage, web-hosting

We have an ERP system with small file storage space and files must be uploaded one at a time. But we can link images from another server into the ERP reports with HTML image link code which looks fine.

Our Shopify doesn't have an FTP to store the images. I believe I need another image storage solution and was wondering what others would use for this. The requirements would be:

1. Large storage space
2. a consistent, predictable HTTP URL link
3. FTP

Does anyone use something like this or has a recommendation? Do I need a regular webhosting server or a CDN? I looked at some image hosting sites but the URLs are not consistent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple cPanel shared hosting account pointed to a subdomain (i.e. assets.yourdomain.com) from a reputable provider would accomplish what you need. You can use FTP or the web based file manager to easily upload your files.

Comment: That's what i was thinking. Thanks for confirming.